# How to resolve my error when uploading files?

Tags: 7, files

In our Drupal site when we try to upload .zip file having 210MB size, we are getting an error saying:

> The file NewEdition105.zip could not be saved. An unknown error has occurred.
>
> The file in the Sai Rel File field was unable to be uploaded.

If I try with a 100mb .zip file I am able to upload. My maximum upload file size is 1800MB, upload_max_filesize=1600MB and post_max_size=1600 MB.

Did anybody face a situation like this? Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Pack & Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/pack_upload) module for this. This module can be used to upload the zip file.

Comment: Hi @Karuna, added some points to the question could you please go through once again.

Comment: are you getting the upload limit error?

Comment: Please add more details about why you recommend this module. Just posting a link is considered as a "link only" answer, at risk to be deleted via moderation.

Comment: Can you please share recent log message what exactly you got during upload the file

Comment: iam getting this MESSAGE: The file upload failed. field_sk_file_und_1_field_sk_release_file_und_0

Comment: @saivijay  try to increase upload limit in the htaccess file.

Comment: Hi Karuna, maximum upload file size is 1800MB. even I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: try to increase the limit on httaccess file like below
   php_value memory_limit 40M
   php_value post_max_size 400M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 40M